# Sinatra / Rails : How to pass user input between views

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I've been looking for a bit and can't find or rather very well understand what to do, I'm sure its quite simple I'm just very new to Ruby and web apps, this one is in Sinatra for simplicity. I'd like to pass the `@multiplication_table` variable as well as the things the user puts into the inputs to the next results page so I can see if they put in the answers correctly but dont know how to, I think I know how to do this with a `form_for` but I dont know how to do that with already having a for loop.

This is my web.rb file

```
# web.rb
require 'sinatra'


def create_table(number)
    possibles = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
    int_set = possibles.shuffle
    result = []
    @answer_list = []
    while int_set.length > 0
        random_int = int_set[0]
        string = (number.to_s + " x " + random_int.to_s)
        int_set.delete(random_int)
        if (random_int.to_s).length == 1
            string += " &nbsp;&nbsp;= ______"
        else
            string += " = ______"
        end
        result << string
        @answer_list << random_int.to_i * number.to_i
    end
    return result
end



get '/' do
    @greeting = "Hi! Enter a number to generate a quick test."
    erb :index
end

post '/results' do
    erb :results
    @multiplication_table

end

post '/' do
    @multiplication_table = create_table(params[:int_to_generate])
    @answers = @answer_list
    erb :multiplication_table_page
end
```

and this is my multiplication_table_page.erb

```
<!-- multiplication_table_page.erb -->
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <style>
        h1 {text-align:center;}
        p {text-align:center;}
        .form-group {float: right; width: 100%;}
        input {float: right;}
        #submitall{width:100%;}

    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Here is your table! Good luck.</h1>

            <form action ="/results" method="POST" class="form-inline">
                    <% counter = 0 %>
                    <% @multiplication_table.each do |equation| %>
                        <input type="text" name = <%= "user_answer" + counter.to_s %>  class="form-control">
                        <h2> <%= equation %> </h2>
                        <% counter += 1 %>

                    <% end %>

                <p>&nbsp;</p>

                <input id=submitall type="submit" class = "btn btn-primary">

            </form>

            <p>&nbsp;</p>

            <p>Put another number in for another table</p>
            <form action ="/" method="POST" class="form-inline">
                <div class = "form-group">
                <input type="submit" class = "btn btn-primary">
                <input type="text" name ="int_to_generate" class="form-control">
                </div>

            </form>
            <% @answers.each do |answer| %>
                <p> <%= answer %> </p>
            <% end %>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: three major options: store in database, use `flash`, or use `session`

Comment: Oh wow I only know of using a db, can you link me to anything about flash or sessions? I have heard of flash but dont even know of sessions for ruby web apps

Comment: Session is a connection specific storage system ( for small amounts of data, typically). In sinatra you'll have to "use sessions", in rails it's built in. I recommend reading through a tutorial on how to implement auth in sinatra or rails, it will give you a good impression of how to use session. I recommend go ogling for the top tutorial